# An internal error occurred during: "Loading referenced grammars". org/eclipse/jdt/core/IElementChangedListener

Tags: java, xml, spring, eclipse, pom.xml

After change some codes at pom.xml, this error has occurred when I launch workspace:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnytg.png]

and then other few more errors show up.
Besides, Project Explorer doesn't show up:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j742E.png]

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
java.lang.NullPointerException

The 'net.harawata.mybatipse.XmlMapperHyperlinkDetector' extension from plug-in 'net.harawata.mybatipse' to the 'org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor.hyperlinkDetectors' extension point failed to load the hyperlink detector.
Plug-in "net.harawata.mybatipse" was unable to instantiate class "net.harawata.mybatipse.hyperlink.XmlHyperlinkDetector".
org/eclipse/jdt/core/IJavaElement

The 'org.eclipse.jst.jsp.ui.internal.hyperlink.XMLJavaHyperlinkDetector' extension from plug-in 'org.eclipse.jst.jsp.ui' to the 'org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor.hyperlinkDetectors' extension point failed to load the hyperlink detector.
Plug-in "org.eclipse.jst.jsp.ui" was unable to instantiate class "org.eclipse.jst.jsp.ui.internal.hyperlink.XMLJavaHyperlinkDetector".
org/eclipse/jst/jsp/core/internal/java/JSPTranslation

An internal error occurred during: "Compute launch button tooltip".
org/eclipse/jdt/core/JavaModelException

An internal error occurred during: "Initializing Boot Validation Enabler".
org/eclipse/jdt/core/IElementChangedListener
```

I also tried to add
`-Dcom.ibm.icu.util.TimeZone.DefaultTimeZoneType=ICU` in `eclipse.ini`

[reproudce error]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrIey.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5beAx.png]

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- Project configurator "org.maven.ide.eclipse.configuration.wtp.configurator" required by plugin execution "org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (execution: default-war, phase: package)" is not available. To enable full functionality, install the 
 project configurator and run Maven->Update Project Configuration.
- Project configurator "org.maven.ide.eclipse.configuration.wtp.overlay.configurator" required by plugin execution "org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (execution: default-war, phase: package)" is not available. To enable full functionality, 
 install the project configurator and run Maven->Update Project Configuration.
```

Comment: According to the screenshots your Eclipse is pretty old and a couple of releases behind. Please upgrade.

Comment: @howlger thx! I upgraded but same error occurred...

Comment: Your question is still about a quite old Eclipse. Please make sure that the software you are using is up to date before asking a question. Please go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error, hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_. The errors seems to be caused by the `net.harawata.mybatipse` plugin. Can you reproduce the error with the current Eclipse without additional plugins and with a fresh workspace?

Comment: @howlger yes sure! I added [reproduce error] at the bottom of Body. Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: There are two things. There are errors in your `pom.xml` in line 189 and 8 about incorrect livecycle mappings. The other thing is the internal error you get. Please focus of one thing only. For the first thing, show a [minimal `pom.xml` with which the issue can reproduced](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the current version of Eclipse without additional plugins. For the other thing, in the current Eclipse, go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error, hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_.

Comment: If the Project Explorer can not render itself, your installation is broken in some way, and that has to be addressed first.

Comment: I just imported project and Project Explorer can render itself. Thank you all, I appreciate it.